# como solucionar el not found de una imagen en angular?

Tags: html, angular

mi problema es que no me muestra la imagen que importo y el mensaje de error que me muestre es el de 404 not found, cuando la importación incluso está dentro de la misma carpeta[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aunque esté dentro de la misma carpeta, ese enlace lo busca en la raíz pública de tu aplicación, por lo tanto lo pones allí o bien en una carpeta de imágenes a partir de allí o descubres como llegar a esa carpeta app/carousel y lo pones en el src (pero creo que no se puede con angular, pues debe esconder todo eso dejando solo acceso al public que tenga).  Es decir, el **src=** no depende de donde esté el archivo fuente que lo invoca, sino de como lo interpreta el navegador, el cual solo debe estar viendo tu /index cuando se ejecuta tu código y monta ese /index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La imagenes que quieres usar en tu proyecto tienen que estar en la carpeta **assets**

Luego va depender del orden que quieras tener en tu proyecto...

Puedes crear una sub carpeta ejemplo **img** dentro de la carpeta **assets**

Partiendo que seguistes estas recomendaciones de crear la sub carpeta en **assets** y moviste todas tu imagenes a la carpeta **img** el codigo que tendrias que usar seria

```
<img src="assets/img/don.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
```